# Dúvida com set value (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, aplicação-web

Tenho um formulário que após a validação usando form_validation, gostaria que caso ocorressem erros, que ao mostrar a view, voltasse no valor que eu selecionei anteriormente no form_dropdown, assim como é feito com o set_value quando é um form_input.

Não achei nada sobre isso e estou precisando disse, segue meus códigos abaixo:

view (que tem o form_dropdown):

```
echo '<div class="form-group">';
      echo form_label('Tipo de Produto: *', 'tipoproduto');
      echo form_dropdown('tipoproduto', $options_tipovinhos, null, array('class' => "form-control"));
      echo '<div class="invalid-feedback">Por favor, preencha esse campo.</div>';
      echo '</div>';
```

control(que tem a validação):

```
public function cadastrar(){
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        //regras de validação
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('tipoproduto', 'Tipo de Produto', 'trim|required|max_length[50]|min_length[1]');

        //teste de validação campos
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE):
            $dados = [
                'titulo' => 'Cadastro de Produtos - WineApp',
                'formerror' => validation_errors(),
                'fotoerror' => null,
                'options_paises' => $this->ProdutosF_model->selectPais(),
                'options_tipovinhos' => $this->ProdutosF_model->selectTipodeProdutos()
            ];
            $this->template->show("cadastroprodutos.php", $dados);
```

model: (onde construo os options que tem no form_dropdown, para não colocar um monte de código foreach na view e reutilizar essa funcao)

```
    //pega todos tipos de vinho
    public function getTipoVinho(){
        return $this->db->order_by('nome_TipoProduto')->get('tb_TipoProduto');
    }

    //cria um select com todos tipos de produtos
    public function selectTipodeProdutos(){

        $produtos = null;
        $tipodeprodutos = $this->getTipoVinho();

        foreach($tipodeprodutos -> result() as $tipodeproduto){
            $produtos .= "<option value='{$tipodeproduto->nome_TipoProduto}'>{$tipodeproduto->nome_TipoProduto}</option>";
        }

        return $produtos;

    }
```

Minha dúvida é se é possível usar algo como um set_value no form_dropdown, levando em conta que estou populando ele dessa maneira que mostrei com os códigos acima.

Answer (score 0):

É só você usar o `set_value` no 3 parâmetro da função `form_dropdown`. No seu exemplo você colocou `null`.

```
echo '<div class="form-group">';
echo form_label('Tipo de Produto: *', 'tipoproduto');
echo form_dropdown('tipoproduto', $options_tipovinhos, set_value('tipoproduto'), array('class' => "form-control"));
echo '<div class="invalid-feedback">Por favor, preencha esse campo.</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Opa kayo, beleza? Então cara, dessa maneira não foi, justamente por isso não entendo. Li a documentação e entendi que fosse dessa maneira. será que pode ser pq estou montando as options em outro lugar que não é na view? Montei na model pq uso esse form_dropdown em diversas telas

Answer (score 0):

Você está lidando com o `method` da biblioteca, e ele tem requisitos próprios:

> form_dropdown([$name = ''[, $options = array()[, $selected = array()[,
>   $extra = '']]]])

Na [documentação](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=form_dropdown#form_dropdown) existem 4 (quatro) parâmetros: `$name (string), $options (array), $selected (array) e $extra (mixed)`.

Ora, se vc usa um `array` pra definir a lista de produtos (vc usa `$options_tipovinhos`), a recuperação dos dados vai ter que ser feita manipulando esse mesmo `array`, como a documentação descreve. Perceba que, não por acaso, o terceiro parâmetro (`$selected`, que vc está passando `null`) sempre será um `array`. Isso quer dizer que vc vai ter que recuperar os dados do `$_POST` pra poder repopular o `FORM`:

```
<?php
 $name = 'tipoproduto';
 $extra = [
  'class' => "form-control",
  'required' => true
 ];
 $options = [
  null        => 'Select one',
  'small'     => 'Small Shirt',
  'med'       => 'Medium Shirt',
  'large'     => 'Large Shirt',
  'xlarge'    => 'Extra Large Shirt',
 ];
 $selected = [//Tem que ser um array, pois o method form_dropdown() exige;
   set_value($name)//Se vc passar mais de um valor aqui, form_dropdown() vai automaticamente entender que isso é um select multiplo;
 ];
 echo form_label('Tipo de Produto:*', 'tipoproduto');
 echo form_dropdown($name, $options, $selected, $extra);
 echo '<div class="invalid-feedback">Por favor, preencha esse campo.</div>';
```

Não é possível recuperar direto com `set_value()` porque, como já disse, o method `form_dropdown()` exige que o terceiro parâmetro seja um `array`, e `set_value()` retorna um `string` ([veja aqui](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=set_value#set_value)).